# Вопрос по методу String.format()

Tags: java, строки, format

```
String s =" polakshfUodfaasp[eorfjcnnxbxaxxakfaaheryo";
String[] s2 = {"5000","8000"};
    System.out.println(String.format(s+"%s", s2));
```

вывод на консоль:

```
 polakshfUodfaasp[eorfjcnnxbxaxxakfaaheryo5000
```

вопрос:
Почему выводится только 5000?

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке форматирования мы указываем по порядку как преобразовывать элементы массива.
В вашей строке указано бурквально "взять первый элемент и вывести его как строку"

Домашнее задание:

```java
String[] num = {"1","2","3"};
System.out.println(String.format("%s", num));
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", num));
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s", num));
```

Comment: В смысле, сколько элементов массива - столько и "%s"  (на практике проверил, если что)... Для больших массивов строк такое решение как то невыгодно. А есть ли более краткий путь? Ну в рамках данного метода format().

Comment: и в добавку... как называется "%s" ? ну если не ошибаюсь, регулярные выражения имеют другой вид https://proselyte.net/tutorials/java-core/regular-expressions/   ну по крайней мере в данной таблице не нашел такие сочетания символов

Comment: @RubenKubalyan `%s` это не регулярка - это соглашение. Таблицу с примерами посмотри https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples
Короткий путь для неопределенного числа элементов использовать цикл и StringBuilder

Comment: Все предельно четко. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

[`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) принимает вторым аргументом массив значений для замены нескольких `%s` (format specifiers - спецификаторы формата) в исходной строке.

В вашей строке только один `%s`, он заменяется первым значением из массива, а для второго значения нет места, а лишние аргументы - игнорируются, об этом кстати написано в javadoc:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `format` - A format string
>
> `args` - Arguments referenced by
>   the format specifiers in the format string. If there are more
>   arguments than format specifiers, **the extra arguments are ignored**. The
>   number of arguments is variable and may be zero. The maximum number of
>   arguments is limited by the maximum dimension of a Java array as
>   defined by The Java™ Virtual Machine Specification. The behaviour on a
>   null argument depends on the conversion.

Попробуйте добавить еще один `%s` в исходный шаблон.

PS: [вот тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) можно посмотреть синтаксис форматтера